# Exception thrown in jpa query with List parameter after Spring Boot 3 upgrade

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an account entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    private String accountName;
    private String supplierName;
    private String customerName;
    private Double amount;
```

and an account repository with jpa query that should filter accounts by a list of account names or no filter when the list is null:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AccountRestResource extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long>, CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT account.customerName " +
            "FROM Account account " +
            "WHERE UPPER(account.customerName) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(:filter),'%') " +
            "AND ((:accountNames) IS NULL OR account.accountName IN (:accountNames)) " +
            "ORDER BY account.customerName")
    Page<String> findDistinctCustomerNames(List<String> accountNames, String filter, Pageable page);
}
```

After upgrading to the latest Spring Boot 3 upgrade this Query fails from time to time with (irregularly... I'd say 1 in 5)

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.util.ArrayList to java.lang.String : `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType` (java.lang.String)

Pom contains following dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I don't have problems when the list is NULL but when I try the query with a single item in the list . Reverting to the Spring Boot 2.7.X resolves the issue.

I have a repo with a test to reproduce the error: https://github.com/Jef-VDD/hibernate-demo

Answer (score 3):

You can downgrade H2 to the version `1.4.200`

My colleague suggest that we can change this condition from:

`AND (COALESCE(:accountNames) IS NULL OR account.accountName IN :accountNames)`

to:

`AND (:#{null eq #accountNames} is true or account.accountName in :accountNames)`

I've tested with Oracle and H2 (Mode Oracle) with Spring Boot 2.7

Comment: Thanks. And now that I think of, the above COALESCE code I proposed was not totally ok for us (maybe ok for others), so I might check out this JPQL proposal of yours.

Comment: And realized, that the COALESCE version yields sql syntax error if you give in the empty array anyways. Your workaround code works well, with a minor change, which failed on the current hibernate version.

using = instead of is in the left part:
```
AND (:#{null eq #accountNames} = true or account.accountName in :accountNames)
```

I think this answer should be the winner here. I deleted mine since it is misleading then and doesn't work well in that scenario.

Comment: @JVDD any other solution worked ?